# Print Columns which have name in the format datetime

Tags: pandas, datetime

I have imported an excel sheet into pandas which has some columns with names in the datetime format. How can I do an operation on these columns. For example, if I try to print such a column with

```
Data['2019-01-01 00:00:00']
```

I get

```
KeyError: '2019-01-01 00:00:00'
```

The output of `Data.columns.tolist()` for such columns is 
`datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1, 0, 0)`

How can I get the values from such columns?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

```
df['2019-01-01']
```

Or you can do:

```
df.columns = [str(e) for e in df.columns]
df['2019-01-01 00:00:00']
```

Comment: If I do `df['2019-01-01']` I get same kind of keyerror KeyError: '2019-01-01'. However, if I use the second way, it works. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Date could have different str representations. By explicitly converting it to a str, it's format will be fixed. The first approach should also work if you figure out what's the str format of your dates.